# How to Create a new Repository in crx/explorer/

Tags: aem, jcr, crx, jackrabbit-oak

Am trying to use the crx/explorer to create a new workspace. Can any one help me how to use this UI for the creating a new workspace.?

> Error while creating workspace 'test.workspace': javax.jcr.UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException: OAK-118: Workspace.createWorkspace

[image]

Answer (score 0):

google search FTW.
Workspace Management (creating/deleting workspaces) is not implemented yet.

http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/known_issues.html

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-118